# Trying to connect to a vsftpd server

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to create a user using this [instructions](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/adding-ftp-users-for-vsftp&ei=ofuXUI6-I8OBhQfLjoHYCA&usg=AFQjCNGGr9dHtbRh1Dz2cKl4A4EAys3QHQ).

But i'm still getting the login failed message. From local or from a remote machine, when i try connect.

I added the root user to the `/etc/vsftp.chroot_list` file just writing "root" (without quotes).

Any help?

Comment: Did you restart the FTPd so it reread its (changed) configuration file?

Comment: @Hennes yes, sudo service vsftpd restart

Comment: Did you add the users on the server before adding them to the file?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg well, what i did is adding the root user. Check my question again, I edited it. `root` is the user that im using to connect to this machine using ssh protocol.

Comment: @user35538: You shouldn't use the `root` user for *any* login at all. And if you want to enable it to log in via SSH, why are you messing with the vsftpd config? I would strongly recommend adding a new user account and working with that.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg thanks, I created a new user, and it worked

Comment: @user35538: I added the same advice as a proper answer. Happy to hear you were able to resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise not to allow the root user to log into your system. Depending on your system, root login may even be disabled (see [PermitRootLogin](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/allow-root-account-to-use-ssh-openssh/) for SSH).

I would assume that vsftpd does not allow root login or some other components prohibit it. You should add a new user to the system and use that for daily operations.

You can add a new user to the system using [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/adduser.8.html)

```
sudo adduser bob
```